# I am getting data from firebase after page refresh in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, developer-tools

I am trying to render a list of orders in the your orders page using firebase as a backend and react as a front end. When I click a your order button it shows nothing and when refresh the page it displays the data . I want the data to be displayed without refreshing the page.
here is my code for following question.

```
import React , {useState , useContext ,  useEffect} from 'react'
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom'
import { JobContext } from '../../context/JobContext'
import { UserContext } from '../../context/UserContext'
import { db } from '../../Firebase'
import Order from './Order'
import './YourOrder.css';
import { Container, Row } from 'react-bootstrap';
import { IoIosShare } from "react-icons/io";
import { BsChevronRight } from "react-icons/bs";
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'
import { PaymentContext } from '../../context/PaymentContext'
import { OrderContext } from '../../context/OrderContext'

const YourOrder = () => {
    //window.location.reload(false)
    const [user , setUser]=useContext(UserContext)
    const [order , setOrder]=useContext(OrderContext)
    const { userrid } = useParams()
    const [payment , setPayment]=useContext(PaymentContext)

    useEffect(() => {

      var priceRef =  db.collection("clients").doc(userrid).collection("jobDetails")
      priceRef.orderBy("timestamp", "desc").get().then(snapshot=>{
 
       setOrder(snapshot.docs.map((doc) => ({ jobdetailid: doc.id, ...doc.data() })))
 
 
      })
     
    }, [user , order])

  
     
      

    return (       
      <div className="All_orders_main_container">
       <h2 className="text-center mb-2">Your Orders</h2>

        {order.length!==0 ?
         
          order.map(item=>{
        
            
            return item.payment_id!=="" ?<Link to={`/vieworder/${item.jobdetailid}/${userrid}`} >
            <Container className="your-orders">

            <div className="col-xl-12 col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-12 pl-0">
            </div>
            <div className="col-xl-12 col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-12 bordered">
              <div className="row">
                <div className="col-xl-2 col-lg-2 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-4">
                  <img src={item.image} alt="graphic_design_ordered-img" className="order_img"/>
                </div>
                <div className="col-xl-9 col-lg-9 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-6 details">
                  <p className="job_name">{item.Name}</p>
                  <p className="job_deliverydate">ordered on {item.orderDate}</p>
                  {/* <p className="job_share pt-1"><IoIosShare className="share_icon"/>Share this item</p> */}
                </div>
                <div className="col-lg-1 col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-2 open_icon text-right">
                  <BsChevronRight/>
                </div>
              </div> 
            </div>
            </Container>
            </Link>
          : null
          })
         : 
         <h1 className="text-center" style={{color : '#c1c1c1', marginTop: 50}}>No Orders</h1>

        }    
      
      
    </div>
    )
}

export default YourOrder
```

please guide me for the same

Comment: Hi, Where is `your order button`?

Comment: the button is on the navbar of the home page , when someone click the button it redirects it to the your order page

Answer (score 0):

You can use `onSnapshot()`, which makes your app "listen" for changes on ta document or multiple documents. https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen

Comment: I have used onsnapshot also but it data is still not fetched , it displays after refreshing

Answer (score 0):

As we know that the data transfer takes time, we have to either await for the response or, you have to use the onSnapShot() method that will await the response from firebase and then set your list of items,

As per the comment , try removing the [user , order] from the useEffect as it will render your content only if the user or orders list has changes, so instead just pass it as a empty list, thus it will fire on startup,

example :

```js
const [orders, setOrders] = useState([]);
useEffect(()=>{
   //The logic here will fire on startup , thus setting your order state from here will work 
    setOrders() //from here
}, [])
```

This is the approach for local setup, if you want your data to be globally available, I see you are using context, thus use Reducers to set the state declare a method and call it in here after you get the data
Kindly follow the above approach

Happy Coding

Comment: I've used onSnapshot method also , but the result is still the same

Comment: results are still the same after removing user and order

Comment: It is because you are setting it outside the script, like you are using useContext instead use useState,

Comment: its not working again , I've tried almost everything but data displays after page refresh.

Comment: Kindly use Reducers, from your Global context and set your data there..